# Conserved current for a 1d oscillator using Maple

Tags: maple, computational-mechanics

I found out the conserved current for harmonic oscillator with angular frequency 1, particle falling in gravity close to ground ($g=1$) using maple. I'm unable to understand the result:

> $$J[t](t, x(t), \frac{dx(t)}{dt}) = F1(x(t)^2 + (\frac{dx(t)}{dt})^2, -arctan(x(t)/\frac{dx(t)}{dt}) + t)$$

For particle falling under gravity:

> $$J[t](t, x(t), \frac{dx(t)}{dt}) = F1(-t + \frac{dx(t)}{dt}, t^2/2 - t*\frac{dx(t)}{dt}+ x(t))$$

What do these terms mean? Also, how does one calculate conserved current for these systems?
I thought that conserved current is a 4-vector that satisfies continuity equation. I'm unable to make that connection here.

Comment: What do you mean "you found out" that? What is the role of Maple here? Where do these formulas come from? Copied from a book, or your professor's notes? We better see the original source of this, to say anything.

Comment: I used the ConservedCurrents command in maple to find these terms.

Comment: Ah, ok, understand now. Apparently those are some conservation laws existing in this system. The second example would be easier to understand, if you make g not equal to 1 so we can see where it appears in the ConservedCurrents. Do you specify initial conditions for your system?